# How actually did Violet get a golden ticket in Charlie and the Chocolate Factory?

Tags: charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory

It is clear the different creative ideas for how Augustus Gloop, Veruca Salt, and Mike Teavee got them. How the heck did Violet Beauregarde get hers?

Maybe they couldn't think of enough ideas so they did it this way. Maybe she got a lot of money from being so skilled that she got a lot of records and then it ended up being done essentially the same was as Veruca.

They want to make it look her strategy was different so they don't show the part of it being done like Veruca. With Veruca, it was just from being rich and paying people to open those chocolate bars fast.

Maybe Violet, since she was the type of person who was able to get those records, bought a ticket off somebody else for $100,000.

Comment: Are you asking about the original book? The first film? The remake? One of the stage plays?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I'm pretty sure the answer/s are the same for all. She's a competitive eater. She bought lots of bars (and ate them). Unlike Gloop, she's not become fat because she gets oodles of exercise

Comment: @Valorum I always thought she didn't get fat like Gloop because she primarily ate chewing gum. I know there probably are calories in chewing gum, but she'd been on the same piece for so long, it probably wasn't making her fat.

Comment: I think they factory scene where Veruca got her ticket clearly shows the amount of chocolate you need to eat to win. Not even Augusts chocolate habits would make much of a  difference. I think everyone except Veruca and Mike simply got lucky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Sheer luck.**

In the 2010 opera adaptation (yes, that's a thing, apparently), Violet got *ridiculously* lucky. This version of Violet is obsessed with staying thin (hence her obsession with chewing gum; it's a substitute for food), and she finds the Golden Ticket when her father persuades her to take a momentary break from her strict diet and have *one* chocolate bar.

In all other adaptations, Violet actively sought out a Golden Ticket solely for the fame and glory of winning one, not because she actually wanted the prize that came with it. Of course, because she had neither the resources of Veruca and her father, nor the appetite of Augustus, she was still extremely lucky to actually find one.

Source: [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/CharlieAndTheChocolateFactoryTheFourBrattyKids) (obligatory warning: this site is a massive time sink)

Answer (score 14):

She was, according the [original book by Roald Dahl](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6310.Charlie_and_the_Chocolate_Factory), simply *lucky*, augmented by the volume of chocolate she ate. She eats gum "all day long" so it's reasonable to assume that she ate chocolate all day long too.

> “I’m a gum chewer, normally,” she shouted, “but when I heard about these ticket things of Mr Wonka’s, **I gave up gum and started on chocolate bars in the hope of striking lucky.** Now, of course, I’m back on gum.

---

Similar descriptions appear in the 1971 film (*"Well, I'm a gum chewer normally, but when I heard about these ticket things of Wonka's, I laid off the gum and switched to candy bars instead"*).

and the 2005 film (*"I'm a gum chewer, mostly, but when I heard about these ticket things, I laid off the gum. Switched to candy bars"*).

Comment: Is that actually what Violet said in the trophy room? She was talking fast and maybe also slurring and I couldn't head what he was saying. I payed attention instead to the fact that she was not innunciating while she was talking.

Comment: I also misheard "ticket things" as sticky things.

Comment: I thought Violet was on a nonsense ramble.